# How to "Enable expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" on mac

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

I want to know how to check if I enabled to expose daemon on tcp and if don't how to enable it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**On Linux,** you need to configure the file:  /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
    "hosts": [ "unix:///var/run/docker.sock","tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"],
    "log-driver": "journald",
    "signature-verification": false,

}
```

On Mac , the path will be something smilar.

I am using TLS though , but if you want to test it or give it a try , then that is the place to do.

But if it doesnt work without TLS then there is no harm in generating self signed certicate and use it.

Update:

**Docker for MAC:**

```
$ socat -d TCP-LISTEN:2376,range=127.0.0.1/32,reuseaddr,fork UNIX:/var/run/docker.sock

$ curl localhost:2376/version
{"Version":"1.11.2","ApiVersion":"1.23","GitCommit":"56888bf","GoVersion":"go1.5.4","Os":"linux","Arch":"amd64","KernelVersion":"4.4.12-moby","BuildTime":"2016-06-06T23:57:32.306881674+00:00"}
```

More Details:
[details](https://forums.docker.com/t/remote-api-with-docker-for-mac-beta/15639/2)

Comment: it can be exposed on Linux without TLS and works!

Additionnaly, according to your linux oS/version the setting in daemon.json doesn't work...in this case you must add it directly in docker.service file

Comment: daemon.json works fine on my machine and im already using it for last 1 year

Comment: "signature-verification": false, is deprecated you can use "tls": false instead.

Comment: For me it required another path to docker.sock: `$HOME/.docker/run/docker.sock` (or you can recreate the link pointing there from /var/run). See https://forums.docker.com/t/is-a-missing-docker-sock-file-a-bug/134351

Answer (score -1):

On Linux System,

1. Create `daemon.json` file in `/etc/docker`:

   ```
    {"hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]}
   ```
2. Add `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf`:

   ```
    [Service]

    ExecStart=

    ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd
   ```
3. Reload the system daemon:

   ```
    systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
4. Restart docker:

   ```
    systemctl restart docker.service
   ```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/styblope/dc55e0ad2a9848f2cc3307d4819d819f